# not able to access GCP instance via SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, server

I did reboot in my GCP instance after that I am not able to connect to that instance via SSH.
now I can access that disk into another instance so I want to know how to configure SSH in disk by changing in files so that when I start that instance again I am able to access again SSH.

may be it is not started with boot because before reboot it was working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The tags are wrong on your question... You speak of GCP (Google Cloud Platform) but you tagged AWS.

If you are using GCP, you should add the keys using metadatas ssh-keys see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys), that way the keys will be added dynamically by google. If you have keys in metadatas and inside the authorized-keys file it could sometime overwrite those.